# ¿Como puedo alinear texto?

Tags: html, css, scss

¿Cómo puedo mover el texto, para que quede en la parte de abajo?.   Intenté moverlo con `margin`, pero se mueve todo el `div`, y con `text-align` no se obtiene resultado al igual que con `float`.
¿Es posible mover el texto? para que quede algo como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML**

```
<section class="presentacion" id="presentacion">
  <div class="containerp">
    <h1> Presentación </h1>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt cum doloribus asperiores rem beatae commodi excepturi incidunt dicta illum expedita, necessitatibus consequatur obcaecati nobis optio dolorum accusantium, ad dolor sed. </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.containerp {
       text-align: justify;
    h1 {
      color: $yellow;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-family: $font-main;
      margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
    p {
      color: $offwhite;
      margin-top: 150px;
      margin-left: 30px;  
      font-family: $font-main;
    }
}

@mixin imagen {
    background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/m-tBORfP4uW9rvZn58rySHkYobd4TXdd_1i3sQAtpV4Rzafppg7HPmH2fdjPZwGfOni_VvTZzPCFqFwTfk5dsRcb3H5XstE8Kct0q0F1agi7jeDPfqSSR8a2K7tpq0zPjkPUlvtdpOQ=w2400");
    background-size: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.presentacion {
  @include imagen;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Coloca el resultado esperado

Comment: Te recomiendo que en vez de poner tu código directamente crees un [mre] que podamos ejecutar directamente aquí en SO usando los snippets. El problema es que tiene que ser html + css, y aunque adaptar tu código a css son dos minutos, elaborar una pregunta de la manera más correcta posible es trabajo tuyo y no nuestro. Proporcionar un [mre] hace que nos sea muchísimo más fácil darte una respuesta pues podemos ejecutar tu código con un click, modificarlo y pasártelo directamente en el navegador, sin embargo como has puesto scss tendríamos que montar un proyecto en local para poder probar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar `position:absolute`, para esto, primero al elemento padre, es decir `.presentacion`, le pones `position:relative` y luego al hijo `.containerp` `position:absolute`.

El padre tiene que tener `position:relative`, para que `position:absolute` funcione correctamente, ya que su padre debe tener declarada explícitamente alguna posición (cualquiera), de esta manera la posición absoluta del hijo es relativa al padre. Y con esto las posición `bottom:0` se refiere a que el hijo debe tener cero pixeles de distancia desde abajo.

Con esto claro, ahora puedes jugar con modificando `bottom` y `left` para colocar el elemento donde gustes:

Ejemplo:

```css
.containerp {
       text-align: justify;
       position: absolute;
       bottom:10px;
       left:10px;
       }
 .containerp  h1 {
     color:yellow;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-family: $font-main;
    }
    
   .containerp  p {
    color:white;
      font-family: $font-main;
    }


.presentacion {
position:relative;
      background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/m-tBORfP4uW9rvZn58rySHkYobd4TXdd_1i3sQAtpV4Rzafppg7HPmH2fdjPZwGfOni_VvTZzPCFqFwTfk5dsRcb3H5XstE8Kct0q0F1agi7jeDPfqSSR8a2K7tpq0zPjkPUlvtdpOQ=w2400");
    background-size: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="presentacion" id="presentacion">
  <div class="containerp">
    <h1> Presentación </h1>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt cum doloribus asperiores rem beatae commodi excepturi incidunt dicta illum expedita, necessitatibus consequatur obcaecati nobis optio dolorum accusantium, ad dolor sed. </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo comprendí mejor